# Disconnection laptop/notebook power supply

Tags: laptop, bios, power-supply, battery

I need to alter some settings in my BIOS and the process requires me to switch off my computer and disconnect my power source. http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Virtualization_Guide/sect-Virtualization-Troubleshooting-Enabling_Intel_VT_and_AMD_V_virtualization_hardware_extensions_in_BIOS.html

However, I have a laptop. Would simply switching it off and unplugging the adapter suffice or do I need to remove the battery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your battery. Otherwise the power will still be applied.